# Python web socket request to qlik

Tags: python, websocket, qliksense

I am trying to connect to an app to retrieve the details from Qlik Engine API. I am able to connect to web socket and retrieve the All Apps using GetDocList.

Now I am trying to connect to a single app I am getting `Could not find app` error.

Input

```
inpt={
        "method": "OpenDoc",
        "handle": -1,
        "params": [
                "5-app-id-7b4646"
                "UserDirectory=USERDIR; UserId=myuserid"
        ],
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id":2

}
```

Output

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"error":{"code":1003,"parameter":"Could not find app","message":"App not found"}}
```

But when I pass the same input from the Engine API explorer I am able to retrieve the data i.e connected to app. What could be the possible reason for this, I am using python `websocket`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app GetDocList we are getting DocIds not app ids , So when requesting for OpenDoc method we need to provide doc_id not app_id